# Python with open file error

Tags: python, file

my python program gets via ssh a mail log data. When I try to go over it line per line with

```
with text as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
             .... regex stuff....
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 90, in <module>
    start()
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 64, in start
    with text as f:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

That doesn't work, the only solution which works for me is the following. When I save the text as file and open it again. But the file is about 1.24 MB big, which slows the program unnecessarely. Anyone know how I can get rid of the extra saving?

```
....
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo cat /var/log/mailing.log')
text = ''.join(stdout.readlines())
text_file = open('mail.log', 'w')
text_file.write(text)
text_file.close()
ssh.close()

with open('mail.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
             .... regex stuff....
```

Comment: `text` is a not a context manager, why do you try to treat it as such? What *is* `text` in your original code?

Comment: Where does `ssh.exec_command()` come from?

Comment: the var 'text' is all the text in the file 'mailing.log'. I think I didn't understand the concept of a context manager.... 'ssh.exec_command()' comes from the module paramiko I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` is a string with data. You can't open that. Instead of opening it you should just loop over it

```
for line in text.splitlines(): 
    try:
         .... regex stuff....
```

Comment: Take a look at `str.splitlines()` too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Didn't know splitlines(), I usually use split(os.sep). I changed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at StringIO from the standard library, which makes a string look more or less like a file.

Or, you could just say

```
for line in f.split('\n'):
     try:
        <regex stuff>
```